# Buttons are not getting placed into Php echo table

Tags: php

so i'm have this code which it's a delete button of rows , however it works perfectly except the first button which it works as submit button of the values idk how. I'm lost how to put them in their places (Under Delete) and how to fix the first button

Code :

```
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row["id"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>". $row["shelllink"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row["shellprice"] . "</td>";
    echo " <form action='delete.php' method='post' class='deletePHP'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'/>
                    <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'/>
                </form>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Ss of the table's situation now :

[image]

```
<div class="content">
        <form action="shellinsert.php" method="post">
<p>
    <label for="firstName">Link:</label>
    <input <input type="url" name="shelllink" required/ size="160"><br>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="firstName">Price:</label>
    <input <input type="number" name="shellprice" required/ min="1" max="1000" size="160"><br>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: the form with buttons should be in a `<td></td>` basicly its a html issue

Comment: What is `<input <input type="url" name="shelllink" required/ size="160"><br>`? That's not valid HTML. And where is the `</form>` in the `shellinsert.php` form?

Comment: Why should the submit button for the `shellinsert.php` form go into the table? It's not in a table row.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in a table row has to be inside `<td></td>`.

```
echo " <td><form action='delete.php' method='post' class='deletePHP'>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'/>
                <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'/>
            </form></td>";
```

Comment: The positions are fixed , But the first button always has the function to insert the values into database same of the real *Sumbit* Button

Comment: I don't know where those 3 buttons are coming from, they're not in the code you posted.

Comment: look it's a table scripted . In Html there are two text  input and a button     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
alright in the php script in echo i have the showed script in the post , 
Always the first button in the page has the function of sumbit button in Html script , i'm really lost . That means when i click on it , it does the job of Sumbit as trying to add sumbit the values

Comment: Your picture shows a button with `value="Submit"`. I don't see that in the script, so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The html table where you can find the first sumbit button which it has the function of sumbit


<div class="content">
            <form action="shellinsert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">Link:</label>
        <input <input type="url" name="shelllink" required/ size="160"><br>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">Price:</label>
        <input <input type="number" name="shellprice" required/ min="1" max="1000" size="160"><br>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 


the second buttons are in the up script

Comment: Don't put code in comments. If you need to add more details, edit the question.